# Where does Hyperledger Fabric store the database for the Blockchain and where do i can see it and how

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I have hyperledger fabric network setup on my local machine with a single validating node.and im initiating a simple transaction, and  my doubt is where the data will store? (according to my knowledge it will store in couchDb)
and how do I can access the data and where I can see that database in local machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hyperledger fabric supports LevelDB and CouchDB as state databases, LevelDB is the default state database embedded in the peer process and stores chaincode data as key-value pairs. CouchDB is an optional alternative external state database that provides addition query support when your chaincode data is modeled as JSON, permitting rich queries of the JSON content. If your using CouchDB as your state database you can use built-in administration interface to see the records, in your browser try to access http://localhost:5984/_utils/ here 5984 is default port for CouchDB.

More resources

1. [Ledger](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/ledger.html)
2. [CouchDB as the State Database](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/couchdb_as_state_database.html)
3. [Using CouchDB](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/couchdb_tutorial.html)